# Will .fseventsd and .Spotlight-V100 in USB Drive contain any personal info such as user name etc..?

Tags: spotlight

I realized when I plugin the USB drive, MacOS will create two directires named `.fseventsd` and `.Spotlight-V100`.

Altough I can disable this feature by running `sudo mdutil -i off /Volumes/<disk_name>/`, I still feel unsafe because those directories are created once and will be recoverable.

I am wondering if hackers can get any personal information from those two directories such as computer name, user name etc.. if I give the USB drive to them.

PS: I do not want to modify the current partition table for some reasons.

Thanks a lot.

**Edited:**

It's FAT32 and MSDOS partition scheme.

I realized the indexing setup can not be persistent after unplug and plug in again. The indexing will be enabled next time I plug the USB drive in. This is just crazy.

Comment: What is the format of this USB drive?

Comment: @Jean_JD thanks for your reply. It's FAT32 and MSDOS partition scheme.

Comment: @Jean_JD this is another question. I realized even if I disable indexing with mdutil, next time it gets mounted, the indexing will be enabled by default. This is really bad. I remember my external ssd doesn't have this problem. I don't know why the USB drive can't remember my indexing choice...

Comment: RE: "I realized even if I disable indexing with mdutil, next time it gets mounted, the indexing will be enabled by default. " --  Open **Terminal** to the _root_ of the target _volume_ and type `touch .metadata_never_index` then press **enter**.  That _volume_ should not get indexed then unless you explicitly turn indexing back on for that _volume_.

Comment: @user3439894 thanks a lot for the workaround. Are there any other ways than creating a file in USB drive. The thing is I don't want anyone to get any ideas about my system information. If I use this file trick, people will know I am using MacOS. I need to give some USB drives to others anonymously and don't want any hackers to get any ideas about the OS I was using.

Comment: sgon00, Anyone that is going to snoop and is technically savvy enough is probably going to know that drive was attached to a **Mac** at some point in time if you leave any trace of the items that would enable one to draw that conclusion.

Comment: @user3439894 I am a very careful user (developer). I don't use Finder.app at all when accessing the USB drive. Only terminal (iTerm2) command line access. I don't think anyone will be able to know the drive was attached to a Mac if there is NO spotlight indexing. Spotlight indexing is the only problem from my knowledge.